# What is the use of prototype in array.prototype.slice.call

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why to include a prototype?

Why just not?

```
   Array.slice.call()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is a constructor function and doesn't contain a `slice` method. It's prototype (`Array.prototype`) does. You can however call `slice` from an (empty) `Array` instance :

```
[].slice.call(/*...*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Array` is a function and functions don't have a `.slice` method, only arrays do.

Answer (score 1):

Better check documentation ,this could help you http://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript